# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery on angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, electron

I'm trying to use [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) to make a simple application using Angular 4 and Bootstrap. The project can be found [here](https://github.com/tiagor87/teste-electron).

When a run electron through

> electron src/main.js

in folder electron, I got the error

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

I tried force jQuery on main.ts, also tried to create vendor.ts and put it on .angular-cli.json like some workarounds I found. But didn't work at all.

I don't know what I should do to Bootstrap detect jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

I removed "bootstrap.min.js"  and my error was solved.